# Set CullFace to Front and Back in Qt3D in Python via PySide2

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5, qt3d, pyside2

I wanted to set `QCullFace` to `FrontAndBack` and that is why I wrote this:

```py
from PySide2.Qt3DRender import Qt3DRender

cull_face = Qt3DRender.QCullFace()
cull_face.setMode(Qt3DRender.QCullFace.FrontAndBack)
render_pass = Qt3DRender.QRenderPass()
render_pass.addRenderState(cull_face)
```

The code above should set *CullFace* globally. But it does not. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the python binding does not change how Qt works in C++.

So you probably have a `Qt3DWindow` somewhere (unless you render to an offscreen or your own surface). If you want your cull face to be active, you have to retrieve the `QRenderSettings` from the window by calling `renderSettings()`. The render settings hold the active framegraph, i.e. if you want any render states or anything else that is related to the framegraph to be active, it has to be a child of the node that the render settings hold as active framegraph. You can get and set the active framegraph on the render settings by calling `activeFramegraph()` or `setActiveFramegraph(QFramegraphNode*)`.

Is there a reason why you use `QRenderPass`? Because if yes, you have to create a `QRenderPassFilter`, in order to set it as the active framegraph on the render settings (`QRenderPass` does not inherit `QFramegraphNode`). This way you can filter out certain objects from the render pass.

But since you want the cull face to be active globally I'd suggest that you use a `QRenderStateSet` and add the `QCullFace` there. You can then set the render state set as the active framegraph on the render settings of the 3D window.